# Paramaters and tokens in a URL

Tags: http, url

I'm a web programming newbie. When it comes to URLs, it is my understanding that parameters can be passed in the URL itself using the syntax like the following

```
http://mywebsite.com/mypage?params=stringified_list_of_paramaters
```

I'm confused because the URL I'm looking at looks like this

```
http://website.com/page?params=stringified_list_of_paramaters&stoken=01234567
```

So, is "stoken" a keyword? Aren't tokens usually sent in a header?

Comment: stoken hold a 128-bit RSA encrypted token.

Comment: &stoken= could hold anything depending on what site your visiting, could it not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The html action is written as follows:

```
{controllerName}/{functionName}?{Param1}={Value1}&{Param2}={Value2}&{Param3}={Value3}
```

etc. etc. etc.

The names for the parameters are matched on the server code using reflection.

Answer (score 2):

Either of those parameters are arbitrary, both the name and value are whatever the developer decides.